# Image disappearing on reload in Safari and Chrome

Tags: images, safari, google-chrome

I created a website for a client as seen here: http://einzigartig-reisen.com/

Notice the clock icon in the right sidebar. Works fine on first load. Now reload the page (by pressing F5 or the reload icon) and in all Webkit Browsers that I tested (i.e. Safari on Windows and Mac plus Google Chrome) the clock icon will be gone.

Why the hell is that? It ONLY happens on a reload of the same page, it does NOT happen when you navigate between pages and it does NOT happen in other browsers!?

Answer (score 1):

Had a look around and found [this question over at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970734/website-images-that-are-cached-in-chrome-disappear-on-page-refresh), and [some other threads](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=68622), apparently this is a header problem.

> [**SOURCE**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5142306/1892635)
>
> Images which contain the "content-length" header randomly
>   disappear, removing this at the server side solves this bug...

You can use a Firefox addon called [livehttp headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/), this will confirm if the content-length header is the issue.